# Multiple queries to linked server (Access db) block Sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server

On a SQL server 2012 I've created a linked server pointing to Access database:

[image]

[image]

It all works fine, unless we have more than one query to this server - queries that are not even related to the same table within Access. When such thing happens, SQL server simply waits with "SUSPENDED" status, while trying to kill the queries ends with "KILLED/ROLLBACK" status with 0% progress and either "0s" or regularly increasing "Estimated time remaining". The only way back out of that situation is the restart of the SQL server.

What can be the cause of this locking? How to resolve it?